# Unity 2D: error: 'Quaternion' does not contain a definition for 'eularAngles'

Tags: unity-game-engine

Goal: Rotate paddle for pinball game when you press the <kbd>A</kbd> key.

**Error**:

> CS1061: `Quaternion` does not contain a definition for `eularAngles` and no accessible extension method `eularAngles` accepting a first argument of type `Quaternion` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

After googling the issue and finding a 'loosely' related forum as well as looking up on Unity forums how `eularAngles` and Quaternion is supposed to be handled, I think my issue is that I haven't properly stated a class to 'normalise' the Quaternion. I have almost no understanding of these concepts.

Code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class paddleLeft : MonoBehaviour{

    private Transform myTransform;

    void Start() {
        myTransform = gameObject.transform;
    }

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
            var ourRotation = myTransform.rotation.eularAngles;
            var newRotation = new Vector3(ourRotation.x, ourRotation.y, ourRotation.z + (5 * Time.deltaTime));
            myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(newRotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that 'Quaternion' does not contain a definition for 'eularAngles' ;P It takes a while to get the error messages but read them carefully and they'll usually point you in the right direction. In this case the Quaternion class has no method or property called eularAngles. As per the other comment here its Euler, after the mathematician.

Comment: Ugh, I really thought it made sense to use these for rotations. The answer the KiynL posted is great though, simplifies it much more. Would these concepts I was trying to use work better for 3D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the above code, which worked correctly, but I suggest using a simpler rotate alternative, as the transform class is stored directly inside the `mono Behavior` body and does not need to be re-saved.

```cs
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, 5 * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: I have implemented this completely now and it works great. Using the same if statement but without getkey I have made it go opposite direction. I will post what I did with it as an answer but I'm keeping yours as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to KiynL I have a better alternative than my original approach. One that is much simpler to understand conceptually.
I've implemented it as the below code. I need to make the number much higher for better result on the pinball and add maximum and minimum range but that's for later. Very happy with the result of this.

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
   transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, 50 * Time.deltaTime);
} else {
   transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, -50 * Time.deltaTime);
}
```